# Slow performances using Bitmap/GDI

Tags: optimization, bitmap, gdi+

OK.
I am trying to do this:

```
while(1)
{
    CaptureScreenshot (as BMP)
    Convert screenshot to 24 bit instead of 32 bit
    Resize screenshot size 
    Get the BMP bits array of the resized screenshot
}
```

I have it working but the best i could get is 18 iteration (screenshots) per second.
I need much more and i would like to ask you to help me improve that.

This is what i do:

```
Start()
{
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken=0;
    HDC mhCompatibleDC;
    HBITMAP mhCompatibleBitmap;
    HWND mhDesktopWnd;
    HDC mhDesktopDC;
    byte*piRGB=new byte[1200*900*3]

    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    mhDesktopDC = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
    mhCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(mhDesktopDC);
    mhCompatibleBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(mhDesktopDC, 1440, 900);
    SelectObject(mhCompatibleDC, mhCompatibleBitmap);
    moResizeImage = new Bitmap(1200, 900, PixelFormat24bppRGB);
    moGraphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(moResizeImage);

    //as you can see to optimize the code, i pre allocate the CompatibleDC (which speed things)
    //I also use the same moGraphics and not creating moResizeImage again and again - BUT from my tests
    //that does not speed things so i guess that DrawImage reallocate moResizeImage memory on each call
    While(1)
    {
        BitBlt(mhCompatibleDC, 0, 0, 1440, 900, mhDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)
        Bitmap oOrgDesktopImage(mhCompatibleBitmap, NULL);//here i have the original desktop image 32 bit (as my display)
        moGraphics->DrawImage(&oOrgDesktopImage, 0, 0, 1200, 900);(here it converts it to 24 bit as i need and do the resize)

        //now I take the bits part of the BMP and copy it to piRGB
        Gdiplus::BitmapData bitmapData;
        Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, 1200, 900);

        if (Gdiplus::Ok == moResizeImage->LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead , moResizeImage->GetPixelFormat(),&bitmapData))
        {
            int len = bitmapData.Height * std::abs(bitmapData.Stride);


            for (int i = 0; i < len; i = i + 1)//18
            {
                *piRGB = ((BYTE*)bitmapData.Scan0)[i++];
                piRGB++;
            }
            moResizeImage->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);

        }
    //here i do things with piRGB but these things are not counted it the timer so you can assume here the code ends 
    //as said as the code looks now, i can fill piRGB ~18 times (18loops) in 1 second. I must improve that/
    //my knowledge in GDI is very poor and i hope you can provide code to your suggestions - THANKS
    }
```

If we look at the while part then it runs 18 times a second.
If i remove all the code in the while and leave only the 
BitBlt call
then i get 300 loops per second.
If I add the 
Bitmap oOrgDesktopImage(mhCompatibleBitmap, NULL);
i get 160 loops a second.
If i add the moGraphics->DrawImage(&oOrgDesktopImage, 0, 0, 1200, 900) call
i get 19 loops per second.
Adding the rest of the code (the for loop) reduce it to 18 loops

Comment: Use a profiler and check out where time is being spent.

Comment: Thanks Eric, i have edited the question - i added times in the end of the question

Comment: It is realy strange that you get 300 fps with `bitblt`. Normaly, a desktop sreenshot van reach from 30-60 fps. Anyway. You are doing redundant things eg you dont need the `oOrgDesktopImage` bitmap. You can `stretchblt` directly to `mhCompatibleDC (1200x900)` and then take the bits from this compatible DC.

Comment: On a modern machine, moving data from system memory to graphics memory or back is often the bottleneck.  You can BitBlt 300 times per second, because it's just copying graphics memory to graphics memory.  When you try to get all that data into system memory so that you can manipulate it with GDI+, you pay a high price.  I would start experimenting with ways to reduce the amount of data moving across the graphics bus.  Try to do the resize and the 32- to 24-bit conversion on the card first, so there's less data to pull.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534141(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Start(){
    HDC mhCompatibleDC, mhDesktopDC, hdc;
    HBITMAP hBitmap, hBitmapOld;
    unsigned char *piRGB= NULL;
    int i;

    mhDesktopDC = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());

    hdc = CreateIC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
    mhCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    hBitmap = NewDIBSection(1200, 900, (void **)&piRGB);
    if(hBitmap == NULL){/* Error */}
    hBitmapOld = SelectObject(mhCompatibleDC, hBitmap);
    //Now piRGB points to RGB data of mhCompatibleDC
    DeleteDC(hdc);

    //SetStretchBltMode(mhCompatibleDC, HALFTONE); //for better quality


    for(i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        BitBlt(mhCompatibleDC, 0, 0, 1200, 900, mhDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        //StretchBlt(mhCompatibleDC, 0, 0, 1200, 900, mhDesktopDC, 0, 0, 1440, 900, SRCCOPY);
    }

    SelectObject(mhCompatibleDC, hBitmapOld);
    DeleteDC(mhCompatibleDC);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), mhDesktopDC);
}

HBITMAP NewDIBSection(int cx, int cy, void **ppBits){
    HBITMAP hbitmap = NULL;
    LPBITMAPINFO lpbmi;
    HDC hdc;

    lpbmi = (LPBITMAPINFO)calloc(1, sizeof (BITMAPINFO) + 4 * sizeof(DWORD));
    if(!lpbmi){return NULL;}

    ZeroMemory(&lpbmi->bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    lpbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    lpbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = cx;
    lpbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = -cy;
    lpbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    lpbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    lpbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    hdc = CreateIC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
    hbitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdc, lpbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, ppBits, NULL, 0);

    DeleteDC(hdc);
    free(lpbmi);

    return hbitmap;
}
```

Testing results:

```
BitBlt -> 368 msec
StretchBlt -> 2,5 - 3,6 sec!
```

valter

Comment: Hi valter.
Thank you so much for the code.
I added it and it improved the timing.
Now there are 24 loop in 1 second instead of 18. i.E basically StretchBlt() is executed 24 times in one second since this is the only line in the while loop.
Few comments:
1) if i remove the  hdc = CreateIC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL); and just put hdc = NULL; then it runs in the same time. i.e at least on my computer, settings hdc = CreateIC(TEXT("DISPLAY") does not improve the time - do you know why?

Comment: in addition to last comment (too long),
2) this line: lpbmi = (LPBITMAPINFO)calloc(1, sizeof (BITMAPINFO) + 4 * sizeof(DWORD))
why the +4*sizeof(DWORD)? anyway i just declare it as local i.e BITMAPINFO obmi; and it worked the same.
3) does hbitmap  need to be release in the end? i have not found any mention to that in MSDN.
4) anything i can do in your opinion to have more than 24 screenshots in one second - to final results is converting the image to YUV format. i.e what i really need is as much screenshots as possible in a second in YUV format (i already have the function that covert to YUV)

Comment: @user3547277 The hBitmap must be released when you are done with `mhCompatibleDC`(see edit). Unfortunately there is no way i know for to make it faster, though i dont get 24 fps but ~70. Can you test it with `bitblt` instead of `StretchBlt`, for curiosity?

Comment: With bitblt instead of StretchBlt i get 700 call per second. (something slow in my graphic card) i.e x30 faster. your results shows 3600/360=X10
If you try another height you will see worser results. i.e when the height of org image and then new image is not the same.
if run 200 times as your code, i get:
BitBlt -> 312 msec
StretchBlt -> 8.5 sec!

Comment: @user3547277 What i whould do is: use `BitBlt` and manipulate the bits with assemply and `xmm` registers.

Comment: So you started to take Chinese?
To be practical - i have not touched ASM for like 15 years ...
Even then i do not think i could write the stretch and sharping part in ASM - and for sure not better than MS ...
Do you really think it can be written better then Microsoft?
Have something ready by accident?
I develop in Visual studio c++ native and as far as i know you can not use ASM in 64 bit and i will have 64 bit version.
What do you think.

Comment: @user3547277 I have already written a YUV to RGB(as part of a mpeg decoder) with xmm registers and it is fast as lightning (a 1280x1024 in 800μsec or 0,8msec) and not so difficult as you think. I cant think anything else except maybe opencl. But if you find assembly `chinese` then this is even worse.

Comment: Valter I would like to tank you so much for your help till now.
I will keep monitoring this thread and maybe there will be other good suggestions